AWS - Kubernetes PVC - EBS ReadWriteMany on volumeMode: Filesystem
I want to setup EBS backed PVC with volumeMode: Filesystem and accessModes: ReadWriteMany
Can anybody confirm if it is not possible?
When researching about accessModes: ReadWriteMany, I only found guides that used EFS, and EBS backed with volumeMode: Block.
Sample configuration that I tried and is not working:
resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "ebs_sc_io2" {
  metadata {
    name = "ebs-sc-io2"
  }
  allow_volume_expansion = true
  storage_provisioner = "ebs.csi.aws.com"
  reclaim_policy      = "Retain"
  volume_binding_mode = "WaitForFirstConsumer"
  
  parameters = {
    type = "io2"
    encrypted = true
    iops = 3000
  }
}

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: sample-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  storageClassName: ebs-sc-io2
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi

Warning  ProvisioningFailed    2m19s (x3 over 5m31s)  ebs.csi.aws.com_ebs-csi-controller-5cd6c7ff95-xxgpm_b31bb3cb-c6c2-49f0-b08a-4a311277f062  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "ebs-sc-io2": rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = Volume capabilities not supported


Does Kubernetes PVC with ReadWriteMany on AWS have an answer for you?  An EBS volume can only be attached to one EC2 instance at a time, with in Kubernetes terminology translates to it only supporting ReadWriteOnce access.

@DavidMaze hmm, it contains solutions with EFS, but I'm looking for EBS.
I'm using io2 which supports multi-attach (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ebs/latest/userguide/ebs-volume-types.html#vol-type-ssd)
I want to setup EBS backed PVC with volumeMode: Filesystem and accessModes: ReadWriteMany
